# OpenInputDesktop() always returning 0 when run in Windows service

Tags: c#, winapi, service

I have the following code running in a Windows service running as LOCAL_SYSTEM:

```
        protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
        {
            if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLock)
            {
                IntPtr inputDesktop = OpenInputDesktop(0, false, ACCESS_MASK.GENERIC_ALL);

                if (inputDesktop == null)
                {
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Library.WriteErrorLog("inputDesktop is NULL. Error:" + error);
                }
                else    
                    Library.WriteErrorLog("inputDesktop:" + inputDesktop.ToString());

            }
            else if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock)
            {
            }
        }
```

The code runs when the Windows desktop is locked (WIN+L). However, the inputDesktop variable always ends up containing the number zero. This is not the handle to the Winlogon Secure desktop as I would expect. Specifically, my log always contains an entry reading: `inputDesktop:0`

To note, OpenInputDesktop() seems to be running correctly as the function does not return null but 0.

Does my service need to be configured to act as an interactive service, or something like that? Do some kind of special permissions need to be set for a Windows service to determine a handle for a secure desktop?

Comment: A windows service doesn't have access to user desktop, Its a security risk. There was a check box for this in the service eons ago, but its not there anymore. the only thing you can do is run the service as the user you want to (in your case) spy on

Comment: Your conditional `if (inputDesktop == null)` looks wrong. To my knowledge, that will *never* evaluate to `true`. You probably meant to write `if (inputDesktop == IntPtr.Zero)` instead.

Comment: Stepping back, why do you feel that you want to call `OpenInputDesktop` from a service?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT What you you think `ServiceType.InteractiveProcess` really is? The documentation says that it is `a service that can communicate with the desktop`, but of course that all changes with session 0 isolation introduced in Vista.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the assistance. My understanding is that a service would be the best way to determine the desktop handle of the Winlogon Secure desktop. After determining this handle, I am using GetUserObjectInformation() to resolve the desktop name and eventually CreateProcessAsUser() to display a Windows Form application on the Winlogon Secure desktop. This is ultimately what I'm trying to achieve. This all works great if I hard program "Winlogon" in as the desktop name, but I am trying to determine it programmatically.

Comment: Hi user3751044, @DavidHeffernan is right. Service running under local system account in **session 0** which is marked as **Non-Interactive** in this case and should prevent many attack vectors. Refer to [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/app-application-compatibility-session-0-isolation-windows-vista/ba-p/373687) for more detailed info.